# WHERE - IN Query Shows Only Distinct Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temporary table I insert values into, something like;

```
SELECT ColourID
INTO #TEMP
FROM [Orders]
WHERE [Order] = 12345
```

Then later on I have a statement which does something like this;

```
SELECT ColourName
FROM Colours
WHERE [ID] IN(SELECT ColourID FROM #TEMP)

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

This will return;

```
Yellow
Red
```

I know there are several instances of Red on this `order`, and the ID for Red is in the temporary table for each. How do I show each instance? I've tried performing a `COUNT` but that returns one beside each colour.

Comment: You aren't matching on `ColourName = 'Red'`, you're matching on `[ID] = ColurID`.  I assume that your `ID`s are unique and this is why you only get one of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IF** I understand you correctly, you want to display, say, 'Red' for every order line that contains Red. Then you need `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.ColourName, t.* FROM #TEMP as t INNER JOIN Colours as c ON t.ColourID = c.ID
```

Comment: Thanks - yes. It's obvious now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need a join to show the non-unique colors for each instance in your temp table:

```
SELECT ColourName
FROM Colours, #TEMP
WHERE ID = ColourID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColourName
FROM Colours
WHERE [ID] IN(SELECT ColourID FROM #TEMP)
```

Should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

`FROM Colours`

isn't that the lookup table?  Thus each colour is only defined once?

Is this what you're after?

```
SELECT *
FROM [Orders] ords
where exists (select null from  #TEMP tem where tem.ColourID = ords.ColourID )
```